# Does JavaScript execcommand works with textarea?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if JavaScript execcommand works with textarea. In IFrame it works but in textarea it seems not... Thank!

Comment: Which command are you trying? Some commands, such as `Undo`, do work in textareas.

Comment: Well all lol, like bold italic, links etc.. you know what lol? if i continue, i may suicide lol, so better forget this crap, and let's use tinyMCE to do the stuff what you think? its open source after all lol, why should i making myself tired? lol

Answer (score 0):

If it is for the purpose of editing some rich content, I don't think that will be possible, as a textarea support text only and does not display HTML as anything but plain text. You could however use a `div` element, and apply it to that instead.

If you need to post the HTML somewhere, and that is the reason you want to put it on a textarea, I guess you could use a `div` for the editor, and then copy the content of the div to a hidden input, whenever the content changes. You could then use the hidden input to post the HTML.

The [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands) has an example of a rich text editor that uses a `div`.

Comment: If like this, forget exccommand.. its a text editor after all, who cares of WYSIWYG when coding web pages online? No one! I will put my auto-completion codes and syntax highlighting... after that, users will save heir work...